# ClickOnce deployment fails to run from URL

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

I'm having issue with opening a ClickOnce application from my WPF application.

When I try to open `http:/myServerName/ReportServer/ReportBuilder/ReportBuilder_3_0_0_0.application?` (note that one / is missing intentionally) in Internet Explorer, everything works just fine. *Report builder* is being launched with no problems.

If I try to do the same thing in Mozilla - it downloads the application file and when I try to run it, I  get an error:

> Cannot download the application.

Now for trying to open *Report Builder* from my application I run:

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
wb.Navigate("http:/myServer/ReportServer/ReportBuilder/ReportBuilder_3_0_0_0.application?");
```

(note that one / is missing intentionally) 
and I get the same error as if it was from Mozilla.
Same thing happens if I try to Ctrl+Click the link from my code.

Note: I've set my default browser to Internet explorer.

The following error occurs:

```
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
        * Activation of C:\Users\Deividas\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE\D5SZ3L71\ReportBuilder_3_0_0_0[1].application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
                + Downloading file:///C:/Users/Deividas/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/INetCache/IE/D5SZ3L71/RptBuilder_3/MSReportBuilder.exe.manifest did not succeed.
                + Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Deividas\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE\D5SZ3L71\RptBuilder_3\MSReportBuilder.exe.manifest'.
                + Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Deividas\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE\D5SZ3L71\RptBuilder_3\MSReportBuilder.exe.manifest'.
                + Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Deividas\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE\D5SZ3L71\RptBuilder_3\MSReportBuilder.exe.manifest'.
```

Stack Trace:

```
Following errors were detected during this operation.
        * [2015-07-10 13:52:41] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
                - Downloading file:///C:/Users/Deividas/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/INetCache/IE/D5SZ3L71/RptBuilder_3/MSReportBuilder.exe.manifest did not succeed.
                - Source: System.Deployment
                - Stack trace:
                        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
                        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
                        at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
                        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
                        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
                        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
                        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
                        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
                        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
                        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
                --- Inner Exception ---
                System.Net.WebException
                - Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Deividas\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE\D5SZ3L71\RptBuilder_3\MSReportBuilder.exe.manifest'.
                - Source: System
                - Stack trace:
                        at System.Net.FileWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
                        at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponse()
                        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
                --- Inner Exception ---
                System.Net.WebException
                - Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Deividas\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE\D5SZ3L71\RptBuilder_3\MSReportBuilder.exe.manifest'.
                - Source: System
                - Stack trace:
                        at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
                        at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponseCallback(Object state)
                --- Inner Exception ---
                System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException
                - Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Deividas\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE\D5SZ3L71\RptBuilder_3\MSReportBuilder.exe.manifest'.
                - Source: mscorlib
                - Stack trace:
                        at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
                        at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
                        at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
                        at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean useAsync)
                        at System.Net.FileWebStream..ctor(FileWebRequest request, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare sharing, Int32 length, Boolean async)
                        at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
```

Full error log file when clicked on Details:
http://pastebin.com/eLJPq9qr

Comment: This is a ClickOnce application, right?

Comment: Yes, Report Builder in ReportServer is a ClickOnce application, but I have Report Builder installed locally too.

Comment: Can you verify that the directory C:\Users\Deividas\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE\D5SZ3L71\RptBuilder_3\ exists?

Comment: No, INetCache folder does not exist.

Comment: Any Ideas? I am not able to sort out this problem

Comment: This page might give you a hint: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229001.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to overcome the problem with this simple solution:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "iexplore.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "http://myServer/ReportServer/ReportBuilder/ReportBuilder_3_0_0_0.application?/Folder1/Folder+two/report1";
p.Start();
```

It launches the report builder and optionally you can specify a path to open desired report (already connected to the report server).
Hope this helps